# Karnaugh map: mirroring tables

Tags: design, karnaugh-map

When creating a map for n variables, we have to do (n-1) mirrorings. I wonder, why are the variables assigned in the way you see it on the picture. How do I know, when expanding a map, where to place the next added variable? 
Could you please help to understand this?

PS: the picture is from the book "Technische Informatik" by Hoffmann.
[image]

Comment: I suspect that these pictures are not made by you.  If they come from a third party source, for fair use there must be attribution.  In other words, please publish the source of these pictures.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on where you place your variables in the gray code running along the edges. If you write out the graycode you will see that every square contains the combined graycode from the horizontal and vertical edge (with x_5x_4x_3x_2x_1 in the the right order of course) interpreted as a binary number.

Answer (score 0):

They're arranged this way so that moving a single unit in either axis changes the value of ideally only a single variable. This makes it easier to read and interpret the map.

Answer (score 0):

The next variable always covers the half section that you add when you mirror the table.